# Ошибка WEBPACK LOADER при запуске Django проекта

Tags: python, django

Имеется проект Django + reactjs + reflux, при запуске вылетает следующая ошибка:

```
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.        <locals>.wrapper at 0x7f121c9e6840>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dmr/pfo_ve/lib/python3.4/site-    packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 222, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dmr/pfo_ve/lib/python3.4/site-    packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 105, in     inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/dmr/pfo_ve/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 362, in validate
    return self.check(app_configs=app_configs,     display_num_errors=display_num_errors)
  File "/home/dmr/pfo_ve/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 414, in check
    raise CommandError(msg)
django.core.management.base.CommandError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
django.conf.settings.WEBPACK_LOADER: (django-webpack-loader.E001) Error     while parsing WEBPACK_LOADER configuration
    HINT: Is WEBPACK_LOADER config valid?

System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).
```

Вот мой конфиг:
(webpack.config.js)

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require('webpack');
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');


module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: [
      'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
      'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
      './assets/js/index'
  ],

  output: {
      path: path.resolve('./assets/bundles/'),
      filename: '[name]-[hash].js',
      // Tell django to use this URL to load packages and not use         STATIC_URL + bundle_name
      publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/assets/bundles/'
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    // don't reload if there is an error
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new BundleTracker( {filename: './webpack-stats.json'} )
  ],

  module: {
    loaders: [
        // we pass the output from babel loader to react-hot loader
        {
            // JSX to JS
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel']
        },
        {
            // TS to JS
            test: /\.ts$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel']
        },
        {
            // CSS
            test: /\.css$/,
            //exclude:/node_modules/,
            loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
        }
    ]
  },

  resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.css']
  }
};
```

setting.py

```
WEBPACK_LOADER = {
    'BUNDLE_DIR_NAME': 'bundles/',
    'STATS_FILE': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'webpack-stats.json')
}
```

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

В последней версии надо писать:

```
WEBPACK_LOADER = {
    'DEFAULT': {
        'BUNDLE_DIR_NAME': 'bundles/',
        'STATS_FILE': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'webpack-stats.json'),
    }
}
```

Линк:

https://github.com/owais/django-webpack-loader/releases/tag/0.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Помогла установки другой версии web-pack-loader'а
django-webpack-loader=0.1.4